# Spring Industry Naming Convention

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, springs, prototyping

I am currently prototyping a part for a personal project. My CAD design was contracted out and there are some off the shelf parts that I need to order per the design (springs, screws, etc.).

My designer included two types of springs in the BOM:

- 3ID x 15mm (possibly 3LD??)
- 5ID x 5mm

I am not sure what the ID (or LD) naming convention means. Could use some help.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This site doesn't accept [resource-hunting questions](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/10/1832), since such questions are prone to becoming out-dated. I have therefore edited your post to remove a question which fell under that criteria.

Comment: Request more details from your designer. ID is likely “inner diameter”. That spring notation above is concerning. There should be a part number or more details specified.

Comment: You need more than two numbers to specify a spring - Looks like you have Inner Diameter and Free Length here, but you need either the Outer Diameter or the Wire Diameter on top of this, or you could end up with completely the wrong stiffness. A BOM should include a part number - ask your designer for this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually spring's geometry is denoted as : OD* ID* Length. Outside diameter* Inside diameter* Length.